# CSS For Fullpage on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am very new and very limited on my knowledge of CSS. I am working on building a website using Salient theme on Wordpress. For the homepage, I am trying to build a landing page or sort of "portal." Ideally, it will be responsive and fit the browser regardless of width or height.

I am using the custom CSS for that page in Wordpress and currently have the following:

```
.at-content {
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #f7f6f5;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: scroll;}
```

I think part of the problem is that I have it as fixed, but if I change the position a giant grey bar appears at the bottom of my browser when it becomes too large.

Currently it responds well when I change the width, but the height remains the same.

Here is the current page: http://chairflyer.com

Any help on how to fix this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use vh and vw to fit the dimensions of the viewport (viewport height and viewport width).

```
.at-content {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your existing codebase, you want to use a combination of viewport units and flexbox.

```
#full{
  height: 100vh;  // Sets height to full height of the viewport.
  display: flex;  // Turns on flexbox properties.
  flex-direction: column;  // Makes the flexbox layout in a column instead of a row.
  justify-content: center;  // Vertically centers your content.
}
```

This will work as long as you can turn off the margin, padding, and width that gets applied via JavaScript when the page loads and whenever the viewport is resized.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. The only problem now is that if the height of the browser is too small, it cuts the top of the contents off.

Do you know how to fix that @Ragdoll ?

Comment: It looks like that's because you have `.at-content`’s `justify-content` set to `center`. I would use a height-based media query to set it to `flex-start` on screens that are too small to get a good experience, then switch it back to `center` once the viewport is tall enough.